# gstreamer-1.0 on Raspberry Pi: cannot decode H.264 stream

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, h.264, python-gstreamer

I'm trying to run a gstreamer-1.0 python script (see below, works fine on an ubuntu laptop) on a Raspberry Pi. However, it seems to be unable to decode the stream:

```
0:00:11.237415476  9605 0xafb0cc60 ERROR            vaapidecode ../../../gst/vaapi/gstvaapidecode.c:1025:gst_vaapidecode_ensure_allowed_caps: failed to retrieve VA display
0:00:11.239490439  9605 0xafb0cc60 WARN               decodebin gstdecodebin2.c:2087:connect_pad:<decodebin0> Link failed on pad vaapidecode0:sink
0:00:11.244097356  9605 0xafb0cc60 WARN            uridecodebin gsturidecodebin.c:939:unknown_type_cb:<decoder> warning: No decoder available for type 'video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)nal, width=(int)426, height=(int)240, framerate=(fraction)30/1, parsed=(boolean)true, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, level=(string)2.1, profile=(string)main'.
```

I searched for information about the error (the results didn't enlighten me) and the warnings but couldn't really find much advice other than to install `gstreamer1.0-libav` which had already been installed. Consequently the decoder should be available.

What might be wrong here and how do I fix it?

This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# GST_DEBUG=3,python:5,gnl*:5 python 01_parsepipeline.py http://www.ustream.tv/channel/17074538 worst novideo.png

from __future__ import print_function

import sys

import gi

from gi.repository import GObject as gobject, Gst as gst
from livestreamer import Livestreamer, StreamError, PluginError, NoPluginError

import cv2
import numpy


def exit(msg):
    print(msg, file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit()


class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fd = None
        self.mainloop = gobject.MainLoop()

        # This creates a playbin pipeline and using the appsrc source
        # we can feed it our stream data
        self.pipeline = gst.parse_launch('uridecodebin uri=appsrc:// name=decoder \
            decoder. ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=1/1 ! tee name=t \
              t. ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=RGB ! appsink name=appsink \
            decoder. ! queue ! audioconvert ! fakesink')
        if self.pipeline is None:
            exit("couldn't build pipeline")
        decoder = self.pipeline.get_by_name('decoder')
        if decoder is None:
            exit("couldn't get decoder")
        decoder.connect("source-setup", self.on_source_setup)

        vsink = self.pipeline.get_by_name('appsink')
        if vsink is None:
            exit("couldn't get sink")
        vsink.set_property("emit-signals", True)
        vsink.set_property("max-buffers", 1)
        vsink.connect("new-sample", self.on_new_sample)

        # Creates a bus and set callbacks to receive errors
        self.bus = self.pipeline.get_bus()
        self.bus.add_signal_watch()
        self.bus.connect("message::eos", self.on_eos)
        self.bus.connect("message::error", self.on_error)

    def on_new_sample(self, sink):
        sample = sink.emit("pull-sample")
        buf = sample.get_buffer()
        caps = sample.get_caps()
        height = caps.get_structure(0).get_value('height')
        width = caps.get_structure(0).get_value('width')
        (result, mapinfo) = buf.map(gst.MapFlags.READ)
        if result == True:
            arr = numpy.ndarray(
                (height,
                 width,
                3),
                buffer=buf.extract_dup(0, buf.get_size()),
                dtype=numpy.uint8)
            resized_refimage = cv2.resize(refArray, (width, height))
            diff = cv2.norm(arr, resized_refimage, cv2.NORM_L2)

        buf.unmap(mapinfo)
        s = "diff = " + str(diff)
        print(s)
        return gst.FlowReturn.OK

    def exit(self, msg):
        self.stop()
        exit(msg)

    def stop(self):
        # Stop playback and exit mainloop
        self.pipeline.set_state(gst.State.NULL)
        self.mainloop.quit()

        # Close the stream
        if self.fd:
            self.fd.close()

    def play(self, stream):
        # Attempt to open the stream
        try:
            self.fd = stream.open()
        except StreamError as err:
            self.exit("Failed to open stream: {0}".format(err))

        # Start playback
        self.pipeline.set_state(gst.State.PLAYING)
        self.mainloop.run()

    def on_source_setup(self, element, source):
        # When this callback is called the appsrc expects
        # us to feed it more data
        print("source setup")
        source.connect("need-data", self.on_source_need_data)
        print("done")

    def on_pad_added(self, element, pad):
        string = pad.query_caps(None).to_string()
        print(string)
        if string.startswith('video/'):
        #type = pad.get_caps()[0].get_name()
        #print(type)
        #if type.startswith("video"):
          pad.link(self.vconverter.get_static_pad("sink"))

    def on_source_need_data(self, source, length):
        # Attempt to read data from the stream
        try:
            data = self.fd.read(length)
        except IOError as err:
            self.exit("Failed to read data from stream: {0}".format(err))

        # If data is empty it's the end of stream
        if not data:
            source.emit("end-of-stream")
            return

        # Convert the Python bytes into a GStreamer Buffer
        # and then push it to the appsrc
        buf = gst.Buffer.new_wrapped(data)
        source.emit("push-buffer", buf)
        #print("sent " + str(length) + " bytes")

    def on_eos(self, bus, msg):
        # Stop playback on end of stream
        self.stop()

    def on_error(self, bus, msg):
        # Print error message and exit on error
        error = msg.parse_error()[1]
        self.exit(error)


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 4:
        exit("Usage: {0} <url> <quality> <reference png image path>".format(sys.argv[0]))

    # Initialize and check GStreamer version
    gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")
    gobject.threads_init()
    gst.init(None)

    # Collect arguments
    url = sys.argv[1]
    quality = sys.argv[2]
    refImage = sys.argv[3]
    global refArray
    image = cv2.imread(refImage)
    refArray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
#    refArray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    refArray = cv2.blur(refArray, (3,3))

    # Create the Livestreamer session
    livestreamer = Livestreamer()

    # Enable logging
    livestreamer.set_loglevel("debug")
    livestreamer.set_logoutput(sys.stdout)

    # Attempt to fetch streams
    try:
        streams = livestreamer.streams(url)
    except NoPluginError:
        exit("Livestreamer is unable to handle the URL '{0}'".format(url))
    except PluginError as err:
        exit("Plugin error: {0}".format(err))

    if not streams:
        exit("No streams found on URL '{0}'".format(url))

    # Look for specified stream
    if quality not in streams:
        exit("Unable to find '{0}' stream on URL '{1}'".format(quality, url))

    # We found the stream
    stream = streams[quality]

    # Create the player and start playback
    player = Player()

    # Blocks until playback is done
    player.play(stream)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The pipeline you've set up appears to be trying to invoke a vaapi decoder to hardware-decode h264 - vaapi isn't available on the raspberry pi, since the closed source X server doesn't implement it.  You may be able to use omxh264dec from the gstreamer1.0-omx package instead.

If not, you could do software h264 decoding, but that will be slower (maybe unacceptably slow on a raspberry pi).